# VSCode seems to have no clue g++ is installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, msys2

I just installed g++ on my laptop via the MSYS2 terminal. I even double checked it with command prompt, and both tell me that its installed. However, VSCode tells me this:
`'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I tried the obvious thing of re-opening vs studio after I added the path from mingw, and it still did nothing
I even added the path to the g++.exe file specifically, with no result
I did also run everything on the command prompt terminal, not the powershell one

Comment: Is that Visual Studio Code? If so, have you completed *all* of the [required configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)?

Comment: yes, i followed each step

Comment: I expect the VSCode PATH environment variable in your settings.json is incorrect.

Comment: that might be possible. where can I find the settings.json file?

Comment: ok this is extremely stupid. turns out i also had to restart my laptop